# Usage of __all__ in a particular file

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the usage of `__all__` in the following [`glob.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/glob.py) file? For example it has:

```
__all__ = ["glob", "iglob", "escape"]
```

But in glancing through the code it seems those are the only top-level functions that don't start with a `_`, so wouldn't the `__all__` be redundant in this case? Or is it a good practice to have it at the top anyways? Any explanation of why `__all__` is a good practice here would be great.

(Perhaps it's to filter out the `has_magic`, `magic_check`, and `magic_check_bytes` methods? Why not just make those start with an underscore instead?)

Comment: Usually in combination with ```from [module] import *``` format; with ```__all__``` defined, everything it has on the list will be made available for importee this including any variable name start with '_' on the list.

Comment: Also filters out the imported modules(os, re, fnmatch, and sys) and `glob0` and `glob1`(which can't start with underscore because those exist already)

Comment: @HenryTjhia got it, but what I'm saying here is why is that necessary since it doesn't import functions that start with `_` anyways, right?

Comment: I think it is enable minor optimization when importing via `from module import *` . Because if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5977a7989d49c3e095c7659a58267d87a17b12b1/Python/ceval.c#L5574) python has to remove the [leading_underscores](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5977a7989d49c3e095c7659a58267d87a17b12b1/Python/ceval.c#L5637) if you don't define the `__all__` attribute. Also python has to go though entire `__dict__` attribute if `__all__` is missing.